# How can I parse/capture strings separated by dashes?

Tags: string, bash, parsing, field, variable-assignment

In a Bash shell script, I'm processing data that starts off like this:

```
string1-string2-string3-string4-etc
```

I need `string1` and `string2` assigned to unique variables, and `string3-string4-etc` left together inside of another single unique variable. I played around with trying to set IFS but then `string3`, `string4`, and `etc` were disconnected.

How can I get the data I want? I'd prefer builtin shell commands if possible, but gawk or other tools are fine too.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use the built-in `read` command:

```
str='string1-string2-string3-string4-etc'
IFS=- read str1 str2 the_rest <<< "$str"
```

Comment: Thanks for all of the answers! I chose this as the answer because it uses builtin shell command and seems the most efficient way to capture the data.

Comment: @Gregg , then you should mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the tick mark left of the answer...

Answer (score 17):

### Use Cut and Command Substitution to Capture Fields

As long as the `-` character is always a field separator and not embedded in any substrings, the following will work:

```
str='string1-string2-string3-string4-etc'
a=$(echo "$str" | cut -d- -f1)
b=$(echo "$str" | cut -d- -f2)
c=$(echo "$str" | cut -d- -f3-)
```

The cut utility does the work of using the dash as a delimiter to define the fields you want to capture, and Bash [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) is used to assign the output from cut to a variable.

### Validation

```
$ echo "$a"; echo "$b"; echo "$c"
string1
string2
string3-string4-etc
```

Comment: You're creating at least three extra process table entries (a subshell running `echo`, a copy of `cut`, and the command-substitution shell) for every single component you want to extract this way -- wildly inefficient compared to just letting your already-running shell do the work in-process.

Answer (score 3):

Using Bash regex:

```
s=string1-string2-string3-string4-etc
pat="([^-]*)-([^-]*)-(.*)"
[[ $s =~ $pat ]]
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
```

Output:

```
string1
string2
string3-string4-etc
```

Comment: This is very useful for situation that are too complicated for a simple `read`-based split.

Comment: Agreed. And I wasn't aware of the BASH_REMATCH. Using this now for something different. Thank you for your answer!